# Coloring the region under the standard parabola in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the plot of a parabola over the interval [0,1] and a line segment between (1,0) and (1,1). I would like the region between the parabola and x-axis and to the left of this vertical line segment to be colored yellow. How do I do that?

I also drew a line segment between (0, 3/4) and (sqrt(3/4), 3/4). I would also like the region between the parabola and y-axis and under this horizontal line segment colored orange.

If this cannot be done using just `TikZ`, how would I do the same within an "axis" environment?

I am curious, why do I need the "intersections" package to be loaded in order for the code for this diagram to be compiled?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}




\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10cm, y=5cm]

\path[fill=yellow!50] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\path[draw=black, name path=parabola, domain = 0:1, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {\x*\x});
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (1.25,0) node[anchor=north west, font=\normalsize]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,1.25) node[anchor=south west, font=\normalsize]{$y$};
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at ({sqrt(0.75)},0.75);
\draw[name path=vertical_line_through_A] (1,0) -- (A);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, yshift=-0.15cm, font=\normalsize] at (1,0){$a$};
\draw[name path=horizontal_line_through_B] (0,0.75) -- (B);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, xshift=-0.15cm, font=\normalsize] at (0,0.75){$b$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple TikZ's built-in [**`parabola`**](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.9) command to draw parabolic curves. This command traces a parabolic curve that starts from the specified starting point, passes through the specified control point, and ends at the specified ending point. The basic syntax is:

```latex
\draw (starting point) parabola (ending point);
```

Here's your final code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10cm, y=5cm]

\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at ({sqrt(0.75)},0.75);
\filldraw[fill=orange] (0,0) parabola (B) -- (0,0.75);
\filldraw[fill=yellow!50] (0,0) parabola (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\draw[name path=name path=vertical_line_through_A] (1,0) -- (A);
\draw[name path=horizontal_line_through_B] (0,0.75) -- (B);
\begin{scope}[font=\normalsize]
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (1.25,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,1.25) node[anchor=south west]{$y$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, yshift=-0.15cm] at (1,0){$a$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, xshift=-0.15cm] at (0,0.75){$b$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Parabola final image]

Comment: Thank you for the code. Yes, this is what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=10cm, y=5cm]
            \foreach \x in {0,.01,...,1}
                \draw[yellow,line width=2pt] (\x,\x*\x)--(\x,0);
            \foreach \x in {0,.01,...,.866}
                \draw[orange,line width=2pt] (\x,.75)--(\x,\x*\x);      
            \path[draw=black, name path=parabola, domain = 0:1, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {\x*\x});
            \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (1.25,0) node[anchor=north west, font=\normalsize]{$x$};
            \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,1.25) node[anchor=south west, font=\normalsize]{$y$};
            \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
            \coordinate (B) at ({sqrt(0.75)},0.75);
            \draw[name path=vertical_line_through_A] (1,0) -- (A);
            \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, yshift=-0.15cm, font=\normalsize] at (1,0){$a$};
            \draw[name path=horizontal_line_through_B] (0,0.75) -- (B);
            \node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, xshift=-0.15cm, font=\normalsize] at (0,0.75){$b$};             
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Simplified code (same output)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=10cm, y=5cm]
            \foreach \x in {0,.01,...,1}
                \draw[yellow,line width=2pt] (\x,\x*\x)--(\x,0);
            \foreach \x in {0,.01,...,.866}
                \draw[orange,line width=2pt] (\x,.75)--(\x,\x*\x);      
            \path[draw=black,domain = 0:1] plot ({\x}, {\x*\x});
            \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (1.25,0) node[anchor=north west, font=\normalsize]{$x$};
            \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,1.25) node[anchor=south west, font=\normalsize]{$y$};
            \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
            \coordinate (B) at ({sqrt(0.75)},0.75);
            \draw (1,0) -- (A);
            \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, yshift=-0.15cm, font=\normalsize] at (1,0){$a$};
            \draw (0,0.75) -- (B);
            \node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, xshift=-0.15cm, font=\normalsize] at (0,0.75){$b$};             
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like the strata coloring using the `\foreach` command.

Comment: @user143462 Thanks I use allways  methos and dont ask external library. This also recall ancients methods to calculate areas.